# Better GPU utilization in SageMaker

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker to run my Pytorch (Lightning) training script.

Why isn't GPU utilization constant, why are there big drops? Can something be done to prevent it or why not?

I have similar utilization when using dedicated and spot instances, but can that have any effect on the utilization?

Here're the utilization metrics:

[image]

Can I do something to improve this?

Edit 1 - adding more information:
I'm using a single `ml.g4dn.xlarge` instance, with 1 GPU.
Data is loaded from an S3 bucket. The structure of the dataset is:

```
dataset.tsv
classA/
    img1
    img2
classB/
    img3
etc.
```

I create a `Dataset` class like this:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset_root_path, transform):
        # Load .tsv file into a dataframe
        self.df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dataset_root_path, 'dataset.tsv'), sep='\t')

       self. Transform = transform

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path =  df_dataset['image_path'].iloc[idx]
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        transformed_image = self.transform(x)

        return transformed_image
```

Dataset is wrapped in a Dataloader with `pin_memory = True` and `num_workers = 4` (as Lightning suggested. I tried using `num_wokers = 6` but the results are the same)

The model I'm training is ViT `vit-base-patch16-224`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have more info on the specific GPU utilization metrics, the model you're training, and the specifics of your data loading and augment. process.

Without more information, its hard to know what exactly is going on, but on a general basis, here are some common causes & solutions.

**Data Loading**: If your training script spends a significant amount of time loading and preparing data, then the GPU can be idle during these periods, waiting for data to be prepared. This can lead to underutilization of the GPU.
**Solution**: Consider using a data loading and augmentation library that supports multi-threading and can prepare data in the background while the GPU is training the model. PyTorch provides the DataLoader class, which can load data in parallel using multiprocessing workers.

**Model Complexity**: Some layers in your model might not be as intensive as others, leading to reduced GPU utilization.
**(not) a Solution**: This is inherent to the model architecture and not easily changeable without altering the model itself.

**Batch Size**: A small batch size may not fully utilize the GPU's computational capacity.
**Solution**: Increase the batch size to a point where the GPU memory is fully utilized but not exceeded. Be aware that a larger batch size may affect the model's performance and the convergence of the training process.

**Communication Overhead:** If you're using distributed training, communication between GPUs can cause them to wait for each other, leading to lower utilization.
**Solution**: Optimize the distributed training setup. Use either gradient accumulation or effective batch normalization methods.